# How to install oracle jdk7 on debian

Tags: installation, debian, jdk

I downloaded the binary of tar.gz format from oralce website. I extracted it to /usr/bin/jdk7. How to "install" it and make it the default jdk and jre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Just ensure that `/usr/bin/jdk7` has the first occurrence of `java` (and optionally, its associated tools) on your `$PATH`.

Longer answer:

On my Ubuntu instance (being a derivative of Debian), this occurrence is `/usr/bin/java`, which links to `/etc/alternative/java`.  Some documentation for the "alternatives" system for Debian is available at http://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives and http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-customizing.en.html .

Alternatively, just do something like this at the beginning of your session (or automatically in `~/.bashrc`, etc.):

```
export PATH=/usr/bin/jdk7/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: do i also have to set JAVA_HOME variable?

Comment: @Ryan - depends upon what you're using.  Not all programs expect or respect `$JAVA_HOME`.  Those that do, usually just use it to help set a local `$PATH` anyway.